# Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my Angular http post request object
The error occurs in "mobile" key, if i use some other key its fine but only with this key i facing :

```
"user" : {
          "mobile" : "9680282793",
          "password" :"12345",
}
```

> ERROR :ionic.bundle.js:26794 SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON 
>   at position 0            at Object.parse (native) at fromJson
>   (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14655:14)

My post request is working fine if i not use "mobile" key only.

Please help me in this problem, i don't getting why this particular problem happening ?

Comment: can you post the entire json ? maybe you didnt closed some curly braces or something like that

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in my ionic app. I just commented the code where it referred to some invalid json data request to get from local storage ( i used a non existent name of `localStorage` key to be assigned to variable) and parse it using `JSON.parse()` . I just commented the line and my problem was solved. You also look for this kind of lines

```
// var loc=JSON.parse(window.localStorage['selectedLocation']);
  // $scope.chatCity=loc.cityName;
```

in this selectedLocations does not exist and it is suppose to parse a Undefined or non existent key value so it returns this kind of error.

ask again if your problem is not solved, i will try to help.

Comment: if problem doesn't solves with this , post the code where problem is comming